# Not able to list the hybrid relays inside a relay namespace using namespace connection string

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay, azure-hybrid-connections, azure-relay

I am trying to list the hybrid relays inside a relay namespace.

I have tried using

```
NamespaceManager namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var _azureRelays = await namespaceManager.GetRelaysAsync();
```

which lists only WCF relays and

`RelayManager` and `RelayManagementClient` to list out the hybrid relays, but both these client requires resource group name and namespace name.

Are there any clients which is used to list the hybrid relays using connection string alone?